# Can scripts that import RSS feeds be used to get SEO traffic?

Tags: seo, content, rss

I have noticed lately some websites that have a script that is capable of getting RSS feeds from different sources.  It then takes the content and inserts it into the website.

Can this kind of websites can get any SEO traffic?  I'm doubtful since the content is auto-generated from different sources.

Comment: Google hastes these sites and generally does not rank them at all. When a new site is found, some grace is given while the metrics for the site are built. So for a while, the site can perform fairly well, however, it will not be long before these sites start to fail. Domain monetizers know this and take advantage of this phenomenon to make money. They can create thousands of junk sites over a long period of time and as the sites fail, new ones are created. As well, ignorant noobie web site owners are sold content, scripts, or applications thinking they too can make money. Does not work.

Answer (score 1):

The rule of thumb in this instance is that it won't increase your SERP ranking, it does in fact have the ability to reduce it. Google's [Webmaster Guidelines](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35769?hl=en) and [Duplicate Content](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66359?hl=en) support document specifically deal with what not to do with a website. Google does not say that you are not allowed to syndicate content (copy it from another website) at all as there are instances where there is a perfectly valid purpose for it. What they do say is to add the noindex meta tag (`meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">`) to let Google know not to use that page when working out your PageRank.